# XQuery: Are imported variables lazily evaluated?

Tags: xquery, saxon, basex

I have an XQuery library module including some functions that take no arguments. 
I'm considering rewriting these functions as variables, to make it a little quicker to access them.

However, the content of some of them are computationally expensive expressions. As functions, they will obviously be evaluated only when called. But as variables, I'm unsure whether they will automatically be evaluated when the library module is imported.

Only some queries that import this module would use those variables, and justify their evaluation. For others that don't use the variables, said evaluation would be an unnecessary overhead.

There would be no problem, however, if imported variables are lazily evaluated: I could import the library module on any query, knowing that these expensive variables are evaluated only if actually used by the main module.

I know that this is just a matter of writing `prefix:myImportedFunction()` vs. `$prefix:myImportedVariable`, but it's an uncertainty that I'd like to dispel.

I believe this behavior is implementation dependent. I'm specially interested in the behavior in BaseX and Saxon-HE. Do they lazily evaluate imported variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saxon will normally use lazy evaluation for global variables. The exception is if run-time tracing is enabled (which may be done if you are debugging in an IDE); it then switches to eager evaluation to make debugging more tractable.

Answer (score 2):

In BaseX, only those variables will be optimized (and, thus, possibly pre-evaluated) if they are referenced in the executed code. For example, in the following expression, $v will not be evaluated:

```
declare variable $expensive := (1 to 100000000)[. = 1];
123
```

The pre-evaluation of accessed variables was chosen because it enables many subsequent optimizations in BaseX. However, lazy evaluation of variables can be enforced by adding the [`Q{http://basex.org}lazy` annotation](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_3.0#Annotations):

```
declare namespace basex = 'http://basex.org';
declare %basex:lazy variable $expensive := (1 to 100000000)[. = 1];
(1, $expensive)[1]
```

Comment: Had no idea about the `lazy` annotation. Great tip; and thanks for sharing it. Apart from that, I'd just like to double check on two key words you mention: "executed code". If the expensive variable is referenced in another variable in the _library module_, but not in the _main module_, then $expensive will not be pre-evaluated, since it is not part of the executed code. Right?

Comment: It is actually not important if the variable occurs in a main or library module. But it does play a role if the variable is referenced somewhere in the code that may be executed. If it appears in a function that will never be called, it won’t be evaluated indeed. – Does this help?